# How can I fix the wrong timing of my fade/scroll animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, fade

Currently I'm busy with Actionscript.  I have a map with diverse worlds. If you click on an arrow icon you will scroll to the other world. The code is:

```
street.street_market.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, straat_actie2);

function straat_actie2(evt:MouseEvent) {

market.bringToFront();

MovieClip(root).worldmap.targetX = marktx;
MovieClip(root).worldmap.targetY = markty;

old = "street";
new = "market";
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fade);

}
```

The worlds are sliding to each other and the other one is fading out. It works like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballEnterFrame)
function ballEnterFrame (pEvent):void
{
var b = pEvent.currentTarget;
b.x += (b.targetX - b.x) / 16;
b.y += (b.targetY - b.y) / 16;
}

function fade(e:Event) 
{   
if(new != "")
{
    this[new].alpha+=0.03;
    if(this[old].alpha >= 0.2)
    {
        this[old].alpha-=0.05;
    }
}
}
```

It all works fine. Except one thing. The longer you stay on a world map the longer it will take to let the other world fade out. So if I stay on the street map for 10 secs and I scroll to the next one it takes around 10 seconds before the old map fades out.

Does someone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword, I`d suggest renaming it in the first place

Comment: Also check if your framerate actually drops. If yes, you're leaking event listeners somewhere, I expect `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballEnterFrame)` is called multiple times. Also you never detach fade listener.

Comment: also checking `hasEventListener` and/or calling `removeEventListener` might help avoid adding multiple `ENTER_FRAME` handlers

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your function like this...

```
function fade(e:Event) 
{   
    if( new != "")
    {
        //# add : ONLY if less than 1 (full opacity) 
        if ( this[new].alpha < 1 ) 
        { this[new].alpha += 0.03; } //# fade in (increase)

        //# minus : if NOT 0 -OR- is NOT less than 0 (transparent) 
        if ( this[old].alpha != 0 || !( this[old].alpha < 0 ) )
        { this[old].alpha -= 0.05; } //# fade out (reduce)

        //# clamp within limits of 0 to 1 range
        if ( this[new].alpha > 1 ) { this[new].alpha = 1; } //# never higher than 1 
        if ( this[old].alpha < 0 ) { this[old].alpha = 0; } //# never less than 0 

    }
}//# end function fade
```

**Explained :**

> ...if I stay on the street map for 10 secs and I scroll to the next
>   one it takes around 10 seconds before the old map fades out.

Do you realise that `ENTER_FRAME` is something that happens **every frame** according to your SWF's frame rate (FPS)?. If you set **30** FPS in your Document settings, by your code you are adding `0.03 x 30` every second for 10 seconds. The `.alpha` amount rises higher than 1, now the delay is waiting for it to reduce from `9.0` back to `1` then it fades out as expected. There is no visual benefit to allowing alpha values to become anything higher than 1 or less than 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the solution. I didn't know that Alpha was going higher than 1.